Cutting Up a Rectangle and Piecing Together a Square of the Same Area
Original Question
Given a rectangle $ABCD$ where $AD=a$ and $AB=b$, cut up the rectangle into some pieces such that piecing the pieces back together will form a square with the same area as the original rectangle. (This is a third part of a question. The second part gives us a way to construct a point $M$ on $AD$ such that $CM=\sqrt{ab}$, and the points $P$ and $E$ below are remains of the construction, where $PC=MC$ and $CE=AB$.)
My Question
Given a rectangle $ABCD$ where $AD=a$ and $AB=b$ ($a>b$), if there is a point $M$ on $AD$ such that $CM = \sqrt{ab}$, if there is a square $CMNQ$ as shown in the diagram below, does $B$ always fall on the edge $NQ$? I am asking this question simply because the teacher just drew the diagram without proving that $N$, $B$ and $Q$ are collinear, because if they are not collinear, the original question would require a different method of cutting.
Note that here, $FA=MD$ and $F$ falls on the extension of $NQ$. IFF $N, B, Q$ are collinear, then we will have that the area of triangles $FAB$ and $MDC$ are equal because of a simple congruence and also $FMN$ and $BCQ$ are also congruent. If we have $O$ as the intersection of $AB$ and $MN$, we have that the sum of the areas of triangles $FAB$ and $OAM$ is equivalent to the sum of the areas of the triangles $FMN$ and $ONB$, which is equivalent to the areas of $ONB$ and $BCQ$. The irregular quadrilateral $OMCB$ in the middle remains the same, and if $N, B, Q$ are collinear, then the areas of the rectangle $ABCD$, parallelogram $FMCB$ and the square will all be equal.
So may I ask if $N, B, Q$ are collinear?


1/ Did you play with the diagram to see if it holds for rectangles? 2/ What happens when you set up coordinates for ABCD?

Hint: Drop a perpendicular from $B$ to, say, $Z$ on line $CM$. (Note that $Z$ need not lie between $C$ and $M$.) Compare $\triangle BCZ$ and $\triangle CMD$.

@Blue So since the triangles are similar, by the ratios we get that $BZ=\sqrt{ab}=NM$?  I'm still slightly confused as how do we really prove $B$ is on $NQ$? I have deduced that $MNBZ$ is a rectangle from parallel and equal lines.

@CheeseCake: "by the ratios we get that $BZ=\sqrt{ab}=NM$" Correct. So, $Q$, $B$, and $N$ are all equidistant from (and on the same side of) line $CM$. Done!

@Blue Thank you!


$FECG$ is a rectangle. $HI || FE$. Let $BH=d,GC=l$.(I have changed the names of the points in your square. Please correspond them to my diagram)
$\angle IBC =\angle BCG$(alternate angles)$= x$, so $BI=l-d=BC\cos x$.
But $BC=a$, so $d=l-a\cos x$.
Again $\angle ECD=\angle BCG=90°-\angle ICB=x$. Thus $\cos x=\frac{DC}{EC}=\frac{b}{EC}$.
I need to prove $d=0$ when $l=GC=EC=\sqrt {ab}$.
As $l-a\cos x=\sqrt{ab}-a\frac{b}{\sqrt{ab}}=0$, this proves that B lies on $FG$.

Claiming $\angle AFB=\angle CBQ$ by corresponding angles assumes that $F$, $B$, $Q$ lie on a common transversal, which is effectively what you're trying to prove. (Likewise, your "by diagram" statement requires the same.) Note that you haven't used the square-ness (or the size) of $CMNQ$ anywhere, which would seem a pretty good indication that you're overlooking something.

@Blue thanks. Is it alright now?

"Is it alright now?" Unfortunately, no. ... Right near the end, in calculating $BQ$ by the Pythagorean theorem, you are assuming that $\triangle BCQ$ is a right triangle, which assumes $B$ is on the side of the square (again, the fact you're trying to show). I think you're trusting the figure too much. :)

@Blue this seems so simple yet it's so confusing, that diagram is completely destroying me XD What if I assume MNQC as a rectangle, and find out perpendicular distance of B from NQ, and prove that distance is 0 when it's a square. Will that work??

I personally made a figure with a not-quite-correct square whose side definitely did not contain $B$, so that I wouldn't get fooled. :)  ... Your rectangle strategy could work. It seems as though the key element might turn out to be a bit like the one in the strategy I suggested in a hint under the question, except that I focussed on the distance from $B$ to $CM$.

I am going to edit it, I think my final comment about my new way should work. @CalvinLin

@Blue please check this out. It's finally complete. I'm still ready for any assumtions :)

@CalvinLin I've completed editing it. You can check now

This is fine, and it's along the lines of what Blue suggested. (The proof could be tidied up a bit)

Here's a relatively minimalist approach which also illustrates a possible shortcoming in the construction.

We begin with rectangle $ABCD$ with $AD=a$, $AB=b$, and $a>d$.
Place point $M$ on line $AD$ between $A$ and $D$ so that $CM = \sqrt{ab}$.
Construct point $Q$ on the opposite side of $CM$ from $D$
such that $CQ = CM$ and $CQ$ is perpendicular to $CM$.
That is, $M$, $C$, and $Q$ are vertices of a square $MCQN$.
($N$ is not shown in the figure.)
Then $CD : CM = a : \sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{ab} : b = CQ : CB$
and $\angle DCM = \angle QCB$.
It follows by side-angle-side similarity that triangles
$\triangle CDM$ and $\triangle CQB$ are similar.
In particular, $\angle CQB$ is a right angle.
Therefore $Q$, $N$, and $B$ are collinear, and $B$ lies on a (possibly extended) side of square $MCQN$. QED

Note that I chose the ratio $a : b = 9 : 1$ for the figure.
For a rectangle with this ratio, $B$ does not lie between $Q$ and $N$.
The rectangle is therefore cut differently by the line $MN$ than the figure in the question shows.
In general it is possible to dissect a rectangle so it can be reassembled as a square, but the number of pieces in the dissection may need to be arbitrarily large, depending on the ratio of the rectangle's sides.
This has to be considered if you are trying to prove equality of area by dissection.
For rectangles where the ratio of sides is less than $2 : 1$, the construction works as shown in the question.

Here's a way to show the areas of the square and rectangle are equal using dissection in the case where $N$ is between $B$ and $Q$.
We first construct the intersection point $F$ of the lines $AD$ and $BQ$.
We consider the quadrilateral $CDFQ$ subdivided as shown below.

Next we move the red and blue triangles to the positions shown below.

The total area of quadrilateral $CDFQ$ does not change, so the uncolored area is the same in both cases. In the first figure this is the area of the rectangle and in the second it is the area of the square.
A similar proof works for the case where $B$ is between $N$ and $Q$.
We start with the red and blue triangles positioned in quadrilateral $CDFQ$
as shown below,

and move them to the positions shown below,

Thereby showing that the uncolored rectangle and square have the same area.
If you name the colored triangles by their vertices and name the rectangle and square by their vertices, the constructions for both cases can be described the same way. We don't actually need to consider in which order $N$ and $B$ occur between $F$ and $Q$.

Another proof that the rectangle and square have equal areas uses the fact that the area of a parallelogram (of which a rectangle and square are special cases) depends only on the height and base of the parallelogram.
Parallelogram $ABCD$ (a rectangle) has area equal to parallelogram $FBCM$ using $BC$ as base and $AD$ as height.
Parallelogram $FBCM$ has area equal to parallelogram $CMNQ$ (a square) using $CM$ as base and $CQ$ as height.
Therefore rectangle $ABCD$ has area equal to square $CMNQ$.
The fact that the area of a parallelogram depends only on its height and base is shown in an answer to another question using much the same technique as above, except that we only need to move one triangle in the parallelogram proof. The triangles for the two steps of the rectangle-to-parallelogram-to-square conversion are the same two triangles from the one-step proofs shown earlier.
